# Terminal not accepting password characters while uninstalling VS Mac

Tags: macos, xamarin, terminal, uninstallation, visual-studio-mac

I am uninstalling visual studio mac in mac machine for that following this article

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/get-started/installation/uninstalling-xamarin#Uninstalling_Visual_Studio_for_Mac

After moving VS to thresh when I am using Terminal, it is asking me to input password but not accepting pass characters.

Please refer below screenshot for more information:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is the password field staying blank as you're typing? If so this is typical behaviour for terminal, just continue to type your password and hit enter

Comment: I am able type there anything. Not getting focus at all.

Comment: @CGPA6.4 strange, as I said its default behaviour not to see any changes whilst entering your password, restart terminal and re-run the rm -rf command, failing that try the command in iTerm which seems to be a much better terminal application (https://www.iterm2.com/downloads.html)